# Gtk3 GMenuItem with icon alignment

Tags: c, gtk

I'm new to Stackoverflow, and really learned a lot here.
So my first Question:

Started to Develop an Application with Gtk3.
Searched the Web for 2 Days but can't find Examples that used the GMenu with Icons next to Items. The problem I faced its that the Icons are not left Aligned in sub-menus. See a sample below :

[image]

The Icon is Loaded from Theme into a Pixbuf.

The Application is going to be written in C and runs on Linux only.

What can i do to Align the icon left ?

```
GMenu *section;
section = g_menu_new();

GMenuItem *item;
item = g_menu_item_new( "Label", NULL );

GError        *err = NULL;
GtkIconTheme  *theme;
GdKPixbuf     *pixbuf;

theme  = gtk_icon_theme_get_default();
pixbuf = gtk_icon_theme_load_icon( theme, "application-exit", 36, NULL, &err);
......
g_menu_item_set_icon( item, G_ICON(pixbuf) );
g_menu_append_item( section, item );
......
gtk_application_set_menubar( GTK_APPLICATION(app), G_MENU_MODEL(menu) );
```

Didn't found a Working Example of GMenu with Icons.
Even the GtkBuilder won't align the Icons left.
The Menubar is attached at " startup " signal of the Application.

Gtk Reference doesn't list any Styles or Properties of GMenuItem.

Hopefully some of the Genius here at Stack know what I am missing.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No. Gtk Inspector shows the Icon as Gtk Image inside Gtk Box, but can't find the Checkboxes or Radio Buttons anywhere. I think it's some placeholder given from the Rendering, don't know the rendering Process at all.

Comment: Why didn't you use `gtk_image_menu_item_new ()`? Is it because it is deprecated? Using gtk+3.x?

Comment: I'm not sure why gtk+ 3.x set `gtk_image_menu_item_new ()` as deprecated. Check this [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImageMenuItem.html#gtk-image-menu-item-new).

Comment: the first param to `gtk_icon_theme_load_icon` should be `theme` in your case instead of `icon_theme`.

Comment: Using Gtk 3.16 so i try to avoid any deprecations. Icon_theme was a typo , fixed it to theme.  Icons in the Toplevel work as expected, but not in sub-menus. As I am new to GTK i really dont know where the real drawing takes place, but i think that would need a customization anyway in the x11 / gdk / cairo ??? used by gtk. So I left the Icons away.

Comment: GDK (Gnome Drawing Kit) does the image rendering interacting with the X  system underneath. I hope you already experimented with the size of icon, ie decresaing it from 36 to say 24. A good alternative will be using GtkContainer to stack up the menu items. Hell lot of a job though !

Comment: Is there a documentation or source information in which says pixbuf is a gicon?

Answer (score -1):

```
     gtk_icon_size_lookup( GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU, &width, &height );
     image = gtk_image_new();
     gtk_image_clear( GTK_IMAGE( image ));
     gtk_widget_set_size_request( image, width, height );
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice, code only solutions can be cryptic

Comment: @RomeoPetruca please update your answer. There is no hint how to use _image_ in OPs code. Honestly, I don't think a proper alignment is possible here. The icon is deliberatly placed outside of the space that is reserved for check and radio buttons, so the only alignment possible would be to shift the menu items without icons so at least the labels align properly.